# Nested lambdas in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to save a nested lambda function in Visual Studio 2012.

```
class Wrap
{
public:
  typedef function<void(Wrap*)> Method;
  Method method;
  std::map<string, Wrap> methods;
};

Wrap x;
x.method = [](Wrap *arg) {
    Wrap::Method t = [](Wrap*) {};
    arg->methods["child"].method = t;
};
```

Which produces this error:

> error C2678: binary `'<'` : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type `const std::string` (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I can't make heads or tails of this error.

I have tested this in g++ and clang. They can compile it.
[http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kVlUY$72](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4kVlUY%2472)

How would i make Visual Studio to compile it? Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is completely unrelated to what you expect:

```
#include <string>
```

solves it. Seems like the comparison operators require `<string>` to be included explicitly, while the class itself is defined if you include just `<map>`.

Comment: WoW! I was looking at the wrong place the whole time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles fine with GCC 4.7.2, Clang 3.2, ICC 13.0.1.

**And** it compiles fine on VC10 as well if you `#include` the `<string>` header, which you have omitted in the example you posted on LiveWorkSpace.

Probably, stdlibc++ implementation includes that header from other headers that you directly `#include`, while this is not the case for MS's implementation of the C++ Standard Library.

Try adding that `#include` directive and the problem should disappear.